# Debian8(jessie) doesn't detect bluetooth

Tags: debian, bluetooth

when i use hcitool dev

```
sudo hcitool dev
Devices:
```

rfkill list

```
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

My kernel:3.16.0-4-amd64

```
lsmod | grep -i blue
bluetooth             374429  6 bnep,btusb
6lowpan_iphc           16588  1 bluetooth
rfkill                 18867  6 cfg80211,acer_wmi,bluetooth
crc16                  12343  2 ext4,bluetooth
```

dmesg:

```
dmesg | grep -i firmware
[    0.166480] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    9.257608] [Firmware Bug]: battery: (dis)charge rate invalid.
[   10.691014] psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 3            (with firmware version 0x550f01)
[   11.742351] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
```

for bluetooth

```
dmesg | grep -i blue
[   11.300428] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.19
[   11.300445] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   11.300452] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   11.300454] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   11.300464] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   84.877650] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   84.877653] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   84.877658] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

bluetooth status:

```
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled)
 Active: active (running) since Вт 2016-03-29 19:11:14 MSK; 1h 21min ago
 Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 1470 (bluetoothd)
 Status: "Running"
 CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
       └─1470 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

 мар 29 19:11:14 debian bluetoothd[1470]: Bluetooth daemon 5.23
 мар 29 19:11:14 debian bluetoothd[1470]: Starting SDP server
 мар 29 19:11:14 debian bluetoothd[1470]: Bluetooth management interface      1...d
 Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

output for lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57785 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b5] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0647]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
--
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0034] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e052]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1bcf:2c18 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0489:e04e Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0000:0538  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

output modinfo:

```
alias:          usb:v0489pE04Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
```

modprobe

```
sudo modprobe ath3k - doesn't say anything
```

for in:

```
for i in /etc/modprobe.d/*; do echo $i; cat $i | grep ath3k; done
/etc/modprobe.d/ath3k.conf
blacklist ath3k
/etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/dkms.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/fbdev-blacklist.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/modesetting.conf
```

P.S. if it help... notebook - Acer aspire v3-571g

Comment: Please edit to add results for `modinfo ath3k | grep -i e04e`  The patch to support it was submitted 3 years ago

Comment: Do you have ath3k blacklisted?  It doesn't show as loaded in `lsmod` results

Comment: rfkill list:
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no

Comment: @Jeremy31 u about rfkill list?Or u need output for lsmod?

Comment: You need to install [atheros-firmware](http://installion.co.uk/debian/wheezy/nonfree/f/firmware-atheros/install/index.html) and `sudo modprobe ath3k` and see if it works.  `for i in /etc/modprobe.d/*; do echo $i; cat $i | grep ath3k; done` Add results to question

Comment: @Jeremy31 i try to install atheros-frimware , aleready last version. Thank you for ur help! I try modprobe

Comment: @Jeremy31 it's work now,thanks a lot!

Comment: You can find instructions on how to install [firmware-atheros](https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/debian/wheezy/firmware-atheros) on the link.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this you need to

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/ath3k.conf
```

You may still have issues that are caused by a timing issue with the firmware loading but that should be fixed in a kernel newer than 3.19